# Print over the internet from a remote linux session locally (on a Windows 7 machine) to the shared printers?

Tags: linux, windows, printing

I'm trying to use a linux virtual machine as a file server for windows clients. I have successfully implemented remote file sharing (samba+ssh) with which I am able to print locally with a little program that I made for this purpose (jetforms style)... but I would like to hear about a somewhat more direct approach.

How can I attach the printers to the server, so that I can for example open a file on the remote session and in the print dialogbox I would see my local printers (on the machine from which I have established a remote session)? I guess there should be some kind of putty tunneling, but dont know how.

I have a windows 7 machine locally; there is a CentOS 6 VM over the internet. It has ssh, cups, and samba.

I have found a question which asks the opposite: there is a windows based server to connect from linux but that windows has a domain, mine is just a simple windows workstation that is behind NAT and has a dynamic IP.  That question is:
[Print from Linux to Windows networked printer](https://serverfault.com/questions/101617/print-from-linux-to-windows-networked-printer).

Comment: Start by describing the actual problem you are having, and steps you have already taken to try to fix it.

Comment: I've made some clarifications.

Comment: I've made some edits that try to clarify exactly what you want, but you might want to read them and make corrections if I've mistaken your intention.